# Get error for using Type object in function

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a function to return Type Object in the class. It is work on webpage, but not windows phone application. The error is "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct". Would anyone tell me how to solve it. Thanks.

There is my code:

```
 public static object GetData(Uri relativeUri)
    {
        return GetData<object>(relativeUri);
    }

   public static T GetData<T>(Uri relativeUri)
    {
        var request = CreateRequest(relativeUri);
        HttpWebResponse r;
        //return Deserializer<T>(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());             

        try
        {
            r = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            return Deserializer<T>(r.GetResponseStream());
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webex.Response;
            setSessionError(webResp.GetResponseStream());

        }

        return Deserializer<T>(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    }
```

Comment: So the exception happens inside the Deserializer method ? Could you show the code and where it fails exactly, and provide the exception ?

Comment: Afte builidng solution, the error is "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it what is wrong on my code. I have extra close bracket that put the function out of the class.